# Winlogbeat SSL connection to ES\Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, ssl-certificate, kibana, elastic-stack

i have an Ubuntu VM where I run ES and Kibana and a Windows VM where i want to run Winlogbeat.
The idea is to send windows events to ES and visualise it with Kibana.

Kibana is reachable by browser from both VMs and the 2 VMs are on the same Subnet.

Elasticsearch.yml

```yaml
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: 10.211.55.7

# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
#
# ---------------------------------- Security ----------------------------------
#
#                                 *** WARNING ***
#
# Elasticsearch security features are not enabled by default.
# These features are free, but require configuration changes to enable them.
# This means that users don’t have to provide credentials and can get full access
# to the cluster. Network connections are also not encrypted.
#
# To protect your data, we strongly encourage you to enable the Elasticsearch security features. 
# Refer to the following documentation for instructions.
#
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/configuring-stack-security.html

#X-Pack Setting
xpack.security.enabled: True

# Transport layer
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ "/etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt" ]

# HTTP layer
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ "/etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt" ]
```

Kibana.yml

```yaml
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both vali>
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "10.211.55.7"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# Specifies the public URL at which Kibana is available for end users. If
# `server.basePath` is configured this URL should end with the same basePath.
server.publicBaseUrl: "https://10.211.55.7:5601"

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayload: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://10.211.55.7:9200"]
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ["/etc/kibana/certs/ca/ca.crt"]
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.crt
elasticsearch.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.key

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Kibana can also authenticate to Elasticsearch via "service account tokens".
# If may use this token instead of a username/password.
# elasticsearch.serviceAccountToken: "my_token"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.crt
server.ssl.key: /etc/kibana/certs/kibana.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /run/kibana/kibana.pid

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"

#X-Pack Setting

xpack.security.enabled: True
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: "cs6cen5MXEzRDQpfvK5R"
```

Winlogbeat.yml

```yaml
###################### Winlogbeat Configuration Example ########################

# This file is an example configuration file highlighting only the most common
# options. The winlogbeat.reference.yml file from the same directory contains
# all the supported options with more comments. You can use it as a reference.
#
# You can find the full configuration reference here:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/index.html

# ======================== Winlogbeat specific options =========================

# event_logs specifies a list of event logs to monitor as well as any
# accompanying options. The YAML data type of event_logs is a list of
# dictionaries.
#
# The supported keys are name, id, xml_query, tags, fields, fields_under_root,
# forwarded, ignore_older, level, event_id, provider, and include_xml.
# The xml_query key requires an id and must not be used with the name,
# ignore_older, level, event_id, or provider keys. Please visit the
# documentation for the complete details of each option.
# https://go.es.io/WinlogbeatConfig

winlogbeat.event_logs:
  - name: Application
    ignore_older: 72h

  - name: System

  - name: Security

  - name: Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational

  - name: Windows PowerShell
    event_id: 400, 403, 600, 800

  - name: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational
    event_id: 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106

  - name: ForwardedEvents
    tags: [forwarded]

# ====================== Elasticsearch template settings =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false


# ================================== General ===================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

# ================================= Dashboards =================================
# These settings control loading the sample dashboards to the Kibana index. Loading
# the dashboards is disabled by default and can be enabled either by setting the
# options here or by using the `setup` command.
setup.dashboards.enabled: true

# The URL from where to download the dashboards archive. By default this URL
# has a value which is computed based on the Beat name and version. For released
# versions, this URL points to the dashboard archive on the artifacts.elastic.co
# website.
#setup.dashboards.url:

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:
    host: "https://10.211.55.7:5601"
    ssl.enabled: true
    kibana.protocol: https
    ssl.certificate_authorities: [C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\ca\ca.crt]
    ssl.certificate: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.crt
    ssl.key: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.key

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
    
    

  # Kibana Space ID
  # ID of the Kibana Space into which the dashboards should be loaded. By default,
  # the Default Space will be used.
  #space.id:

# =============================== Elastic Cloud ================================

# These settings simplify using Winlogbeat with the Elastic Cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

# The cloud.id setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` and
# `setup.kibana.host` options.
# You can find the `cloud.id` in the Elastic Cloud web UI.
#cloud.id:

# The cloud.auth setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.username` and
# `output.elasticsearch.password` settings. The format is `<user>:<pass>`.
#cloud.auth:

# ================================== Outputs ===================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ['https://10.211.55.7:9200']
output.elasticsearch.protocol: https
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.crt
output.elasticsearch.ssl.key: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.key
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities: [C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\ca\ca.crt]
username: elastic
password: cs6cen5MXEzRDQpfvK5R
# ssl:
#    enabled: false
#    ca_trusted_fingerprint: "b9a10bbe64ee9826abeda6546fc988c8bf798b41957c33d05db736716513dc9c" 


  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  #protocol: "https"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"
# Pipeline to route events to security, sysmon or powershell pipelines
pipeline: "winlogbeat-%{[agent.version]}-routing"

# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~

# ================================== Logging ===================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publisher", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]

# ============================= X-Pack Monitoring ==============================
# Winlogbeat can export internal metrics to a central Elasticsearch monitoring
# cluster.  This requires xpack monitoring to be enabled in Elasticsearch.  The
# reporting is disabled by default.

# Set to true to enable the monitoring reporter.
#monitoring.enabled: false

# Sets the UUID of the Elasticsearch cluster under which monitoring data for this
# Winlogbeat instance will appear in the Stack Monitoring UI. If output.elasticsearch
# is enabled, the UUID is derived from the Elasticsearch cluster referenced by output.elasticsearch.
#monitoring.cluster_uuid:

# Uncomment to send the metrics to Elasticsearch. Most settings from the
# Elasticsearch output are accepted here as well.
# Note that the settings should point to your Elasticsearch *monitoring* cluster.
# Any setting that is not set is automatically inherited from the Elasticsearch
# output configuration, so if you have the Elasticsearch output configured such
# that it is pointing to your Elasticsearch monitoring cluster, you can simply
# uncomment the following line.
#monitoring.elasticsearch:

# ============================== Instrumentation ===============================

# Instrumentation support for the winlogbeat.
#instrumentation:
    # Set to true to enable instrumentation of winlogbeat.
    #enabled: false

    # Environment in which winlogbeat is running on (eg: staging, production, etc.)
    #environment: ""

    # APM Server hosts to report instrumentation results to.
    #hosts:
    #  - http://localhost:8200

    # API Key for the APM Server(s).
    # If api_key is set then secret_token will be ignored.
    #api_key:

    # Secret token for the APM Server(s).
    #secret_token:


# ================================= Migration ==================================

# This allows to enable 6.7 migration aliases
#migration.6_to_7.enabled: true
```

When I try to start Winlogbeat as a service, I receive this error:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat> Start-Service winlogbeat
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'winlogbeat (winlogbeat)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service winlogbeat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

The output of ".\winlogbeat.exe -c winlogbeat.yml -e -v -d "*" is:

```json
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2022-10-14T16:19:35.034+0200","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1056},"message":"Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to https://10.211.55.7:5601/api/status fails: Unauthorized: %!w(<nil>). Response: {\"statusCode\":401,\"error\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}","service.name":"winlogbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to https://10.211.55.7:5601/api/status fails: Unauthorized: %!w(<nil>). Response: {"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

`"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"` does not hint to an issue with your SSL certificates. But with the login mechanism.

`request to https://10.211.55.7:5601/api/status fails: Unauthorized: %!w(<nil>)` This bit hints toward an issue with defining the user. `<nil>` being go `null` if I am not wrong.

## Error

In you winlogbeat.yml, as you can read in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/winlogbeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html)

```yaml
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ['https://10.211.55.7:9200']
output.elasticsearch.protocol: https
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.crt
output.elasticsearch.ssl.key: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.key
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities: [C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\ca\ca.crt]
username: elastic # <- not defined correctly
password: cs6cen5MXEzRDQpfvK5R # <- not defined correctly
```

## Solution

```yaml
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ['https://10.211.55.7:9200']
output.elasticsearch.protocol: https
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.crt
output.elasticsearch.ssl.key: C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\Winlogbeat.key
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities: [C:\Program Files\Winlogbeat\certs\ca\ca.crt]
output.elasticsearch.username: elastic
output.elasticsearch.password: cs6cen5MXEzRDQpfvK5R
```